# What is the codefirst syntax to add a simple list of an elementary type to a database table?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Hopefully I simplified everything well to focus on my question. I am defining a class to create a database using code first EF.  When I do the following:

```
Public Class question
  Public Property QuestionID As Integer
  Public Property Answers As String
End Class
```

I get this in the migration file:

```
CreateTable(
  "dbo.questions",
  Function(c) New With
    {
      .QuestionID = c.Int(nullable:=False, identity:=True),
      .Answers = c.String()
    }) _
  .PrimaryKey(Function(t) t.QuestionID)
```

So far, good.  Now, when I try to change the second property to be a list of string as follows:

```
Public Class question
  Public Property QuestionID As Integer
  Public Property Answers As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

I get this in the migration file:

```
  CreateTable(
    "dbo.questions",
    Function(c) New With
      {
        .QuestionID = c.Int(nullable:=False, identity:=True)
      }) _
    .PrimaryKey(Function(t) t.QuestionID)
```

The way I've written it does not generate a list of strings.  Hopefully someone can illuminate the basic concept I'm missing here.

Comment: EF does not support collections of primitive types. You have to either concatenate and split or use entities.

Comment: I understand in a basic sense what concatenate and split mean, but I don't understand what that means in your answer; can you elaborate for me?  Regarding entities, are you teaching me that if I really want a list of string, I have to define a separate Class that has an ID key field and then defines a property that is a string?

Comment: 1) A list of string would be just a string (nvarchar) column in the database. So you need to make your list property `[NotMapped]` and have an internal/private property used by EF where getter is concatenating the list of strings to a single string using a separator and setter would split a single string and initialize the list. 2) Yes - think how a list of string could be stored in the DB?

Comment: Got it. Thx. Is the get/set idea better or quicker in execution than creating a secondary table?  Am I correct in thinking that the get/set idea would store as many elements as you need since the practical limit for nvarchar is pretty big? On a practical point regarding SO, how do we show an answer is given when it's in the comments?  Should I post my particular solution below, or would you rather make that post or do we just reference your comments in the post?

Comment: 1) I would go with a separate table. Storing multiple value in one field while doable is not really a clean solution and may be limiting - you won't be able to do some operations on db side (like searches). 
2) I could post an answer you would accept but someone has already posted their answer which basically is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a text field with the answers, no!

You need to create a new table, the Answers table, then add a ForeignKey to your question table like this:

```
Public Class question
Public Property QuestionID As Integer
'Public Property Answers As String

Public Overridable Property Answers() as ICollection (Of Answer)
End Class

Public Class Answer
Public Property ID As Integer
Public Property questionID as Integer
Public Property Answers As String

<ForeignKey("questionID")>
Public Overridable Property Question as question

End Class
```

Then you just do this (C#):

```
IEnumerable<answer>  answers=question1.Answers.ToList();
```